# How to advance File line reader to next line?

Tags: ruby

I have a scenario in a script I'm writing where I do:

**full gist:  https://gist.github.com/calebtote/8337449**

```
sourceFile.each_line do |line|
    if (line.start_with?(*criteria)) then 
        buffer << line
        buffer << "\n\n"
    end
end
```

However, I want to add additional criteria to this that aren't as straightforward. For example, I would like to be able to parse exceptions, which may not be single line events.. so in pseudo, I want something similar to:

```
sourceFile.each_line do |line|
    if (line.start_with?(*criteria)) then 
        buffer << line
        buffer << "\n\n"
    elsif (line.start_with?("Exception:")) then
            buffer << line
            line.advance #<- not sure what do to here
            while !line.chomp.empty?
    end
end
```

---

### Edit 1:

Clarification on expected inputs / outputs:

```
# input file
13:37:09:299         DBA               20      
SELECT Name from Table


Exception: Error code 50100
Description: Bad stuff!
Line number 243, File name: myfile.cpp
Time: 12/31/2013 08:24:20

13:37:09:301         Identity_FW       10      
In ApplicationIdentity::operator==
```

---

```
#output file
Exception: Error code 50100
Description: Bad stuff!
Line number 243, File name: myfile.cpp
Time: 12/31/2013 08:24:20
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't do the trick

Comment: We probably need a more comprehensive example of your input.

Comment: @ctote that link is somewhat helpful, but what is not clear is the format of your input and the expected output.

Comment: @Max updated my original post

Answer (score 1):

If that's all you're doing, there's no need to parse line-by-line.

```
destFile.puts sourceFile.read.split("\n\n").select { |x| x =~ /^Exception: / }
```

Comment: I need the lines after the Exception - not just the line beginning with "Exception:"

Comment: Myabe I've misunderstood then - what does the select portion do?

Comment: The `split` splits the text into blocks separated by double newlines, then the `select` returns all blocks where _one of the lines_ starts with "Exception: ". If you try the code on the example input you posted, you will see this.

Comment: Ah ok, very neat - my only issue now is that I need to maintain the order of things. So if I get to an SQL statement before and after this Exception:, the order in the output file should maintain that

Comment: `split` and `select` both maintain order. However your `select` block will need to be more complicated (i.e. more regexps) if you want to get more than just the exception blocks.

Comment: I think one option might just be to parse the file for Exception: blocks, and then maintain the loop I have only when we run into a line that starts with Exception:, just pop the top block off some sort of container that has all of the Exception: blocks

Answer (score 0):

Ruby's Enumerable has a nice method called [`slice_before`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_before) that makes this sort of task easy.

Starting with a "test.log" that looks like:

```
#begin log data above this

Exception: Error code 50100
Description: Bad stuff!
Line number 243, File name: myfile.cpp
Time: 12/31/2013 08:24:20

#continue log
#continue log
#continue log
#continue log

Exception: Error code 50100
Description: Bad stuff!
Line number 243, File name: myfile.cpp
Time: 12/31/2013 08:24:20

#continue log
#continue log
#continue log
#continue log
```

This code will break it down into chunks you can parse easily:

```
File.foreach('test.log').slice_before(/^\s*$/).to_a 
# => [["#begin log data above this\n"],
#     ["\n",
#      "Exception: Error code 50100\n",
#      "Description: Bad stuff!\n",
#      "Line number 243, File name: myfile.cpp\n",
#      "Time: 12/31/2013 08:24:20\n"],
#     ["\n",
#      "#continue log\n",
#      "#continue log\n",
#      "#continue log\n",
#      "#continue log\n"],
#     ["\n",
#      "Exception: Error code 50100\n",
#      "Description: Bad stuff!\n",
#      "Line number 243, File name: myfile.cpp\n",
#      "Time: 12/31/2013 08:24:20\n"],
#     ["\n",
#      "#continue log\n",
#      "#continue log\n",
#      "#continue log\n",
#      "#continue log\n"]]
```

You don't need `to_a` to loop over it. Do something like:

```
File.foreach('test.log').slice_before(/^\s*$/).each do |chunk|
  # process the chunk
end
```

Instead of `foreach` you can use [`readlines`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/IO.html#method-c-readlines). The end result should be the same.